# I got an error at compile Nestjs with typeorm

Tags: mysql, typescript, backend, nestjs, typeorm

I got an error when I add the entity.ts into the project

here ts file:

```
import { Column, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm";


@Entity('Usuario')
export class UsuarioIdentity
{
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn() id: number;

    @Column('text') username: string;

    @Column('text') password: string;
}
```

my ormconfig:

```
{
    "type": "mysql",
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": "3306",
    "username": "root",
    "password": "password",
    "database": "blogdb",
    "synchronize": true,
    "logging": true,
    "entities": ["src/Entidades/*.entity{.ts,.js}", "dist/Entidades/*.entity{.ts,.js}"]
}
```

Error:

> ```
> [Nest] 21736   - 2021-06-03 3:04:09 PM   [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
> [Nest] 21736   - 2021-06-03 3:04:09 PM   [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized >+148ms
> [Nest] 21736   - 2021-06-03 3:04:09 PM   [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +2ms
> [Nest] 21736   - 2021-06-03 3:04:09 PM   [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. 
> Retrying (1)... +21ms
> import { Column, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm";
>    ^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
>     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:721:23)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
>     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
>     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
>     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
>     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
>     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
>     at E:\Proyectos_ejemplos\React- 
> NestJS\Back2\node_modules\typeorm\util\DirectoryExportedClassesLoader.js:42:39
>     at Array.map (<anonymous>)
>     at Object.importClassesFromDirectories (E:\Proyectos_ejemplos\React- 
> NestJS\Back2\node_modules\typeorm\util\DirectoryExportedClassesLoader.js:42:10)
> ```

if I comment de entity or I delete it, everything works.
I am using NestJS 7.6.15 and typeorm  0.2.34

Please help me :D

******UPDATE******

Here my tsconfig, I think it would be the outDir

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true
  }
}
```

Comment: which command are you using to start the app? btw show us your tsconfig file please

Comment: I use 'npm run start' and I have just added my tsconfig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your `entities` in ORM config file to:

```js
"entities": ["dist/Entidades/*.entity{.ts,.js}"]
```